# How to connect Google Colab with server-local runtime

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I would like to connect Colab with my university server in order not to have problem with runtime. Can someone guide me how to do it and also what info do I need from the server in order to connect?

Comment: Is this answer your question? https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html

Comment: @raspiduino not fully

Comment: Same here. Did you figure a way? Connecting to a local runtime seemed to be a method but that would require a migrate to Jupyter.

Comment: @ablam no I didn't find any solution. I contacted the IT department that is maintaining the server and we made a jupyter notebook connected with the supercomputer. If you find any other solution post it please

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out what you want exactly but if you just need to be connected in Colab there are several ways that you can do first of that you are allowed to install [google Colab Extention](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colab-alive/eookkckfbbgnhdgcbfbicoahejkdoele)

or you can make a function to reconnect you to Colab

```
import IPython
from google.colab import output

display(IPython.display.Javascript('''
 function ClickConnect(){
   btn = document.querySelector("colab-connect-button")
   if (btn != null){
     console.log("Click colab-connect-button"); 
     btn.click() 
     }
   
   btn = document.getElementById('ok')
   if (btn != null){
     console.log("Click reconnect"); 
     btn.click() 
     }
  }
  
setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
'''))

print("Done.")
```

that i got from [here](https://github.com/chervonij/DFL-Colab/blob/master/DFL_Colab.ipynb)

if you want to make an ssh connection you can use ngrok by this code

```
import random, string, urllib.request, json, getpass

#Generate root password
password = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for i in range(20))

#Download ngrok
! wget -q -c -nc https://bin.equinox.io/c/4VmDzA7iaHb/ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip
! unzip -qq -n ngrok-stable-linux-amd64.zip

#Setup sshd
! apt-get install -qq -o=Dpkg::Use-Pty=0 openssh-server pwgen > /dev/null

#Set root password
! echo root:$password | chpasswd
! mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
! echo "PermitRootLogin yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
! echo "PasswordAuthentication yes" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
! echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64-nvidia" >> /root/.bashrc
! echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /root/.bashrc

#Run sshd
get_ipython().system_raw('/usr/sbin/sshd -D &')

#Ask token
print("Copy authtoken from https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth")
authtoken = getpass.getpass()

#Create tunnel
get_ipython().system_raw('./ngrok authtoken $authtoken && ./ngrok tcp 22 &')

#Get public address and print connect command
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels') as response:
  data = json.loads(response.read().decode())
  (host, port) = data['tunnels'][0]['public_url'][6:].split(':')
  print(f'SSH command: ssh -p{port} root@{host}')

#Print root password
print(f'Root password: {password}')
```